# C++: freeing and a "finally" equivalent

Tags: c++, exception, memory-leaks, finally

I'm allocating some memory inside a function dynamically, and want to make sure it's freed regardless of whether an exception occurs.

Obviously, if it were on the stack, then RAII and stack unwinding would take care of it, but I wondered what the best practice is for dynamically allocated memory.

Example:

```
int copyInt(int n) throw(int) { // this function leaves exceptions for the caller to handle
    int ret_val;
    try {
        int *arr = new int[n]; // dynamically allocate some memory for the computation
        maybe_throw(arr);
        for (int ii=0; ii<n; ++ii) arr[ii]=ii+1; // clever algorithm requiring n ints.
        maybe_throw_again(arr);
        ret_val = arr[n-1];                    // ----"----
    } finally {       // syntax error, this is what you'd do in Java.
        delete arr;   // prevent leak, whether exception occurs or not.
    }
    return ret_val;
}
```

Comment: Java and C++ both have `throws` statement, except it is deprecated in the latter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, use a [smart pointer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) to manage a dynamically allocated object (or array).

Typically a `std::unique_ptr<>` : it will guarantee the destruction of your object, even if an exception is thrown (for the same reason that your quote for stack allocated objects : smart pointers are RAII wrappers around dynamically allocated objects or arrays of objects)

It works equally well for arrays :

> 1) Manages the lifetime of a single object (e.g. allocated with new)
>
> 2) Manages the lifetime of a dynamically-allocated array of objects
>   (e.g. allocated with new[])

On your code : (removing `try/catch/finally` since the cleaning now occurs automatically)

```
int copyInt(int n)
{
    int ret_val;

    std::unique_ptr<int[]> arr = std::unique_ptr<int[]>(new int[n]); 
    for (int ii=0; ii<n; ++ii) 
        arr[ii]=ii+1;

    return arr[n-1]+1;
}
```

- In your example, you might also consider `std::array<>` or `std::vector<>` to replace C-style arrays, but that's probably another question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and explanation for the general case :-) (and for suggesting std::)

Answer (score 2):

The best practice is to rewrite your code to use RAII. The C++ standard library has a lot of container classes to help you with this; these containers have been designed with exception-safety in mind.

In this case:

```
int copyInt(int n)
{
    if ( n < 1 )
        return 0;  // or throw something

    std::vector<int> arr(n);
    maybe_throw(&arr[0]);

    // clever algorithm
    std::iota( arr.begin(), arr.end(), 1 );

    maybe_throw(&arr[0]);
    return arr[n-1] + 1;
}
```

I'm not sure if you understand `throw(int)` correctly: it means that if your function throws any other sort of exception then the program is aborted.  Although it lets the caller know that the caller only has to handle exceptions of type `int`; functions with no exception specification also may leave exceptions for the caller to handle.

I'd recommend just not using an exception specification in this case. If you do use one then you should include handling for any exceptions that do not meet the specification, otherwise it is a bad idea to use it in the first place (as this prevents functions further up from catching the exception).

Comment: Thanks for the modern, idiomatic way of doing it (and for fixing one of the two bugs haha). The throw(int) thing was just to make it obvious that exceptions were intended, even if it is now a depreciated feature, but thanks.